# Efficiently subdivide a bezier curve in javascript

Tags: javascript, bezier

Given the start and end points and the two control points of a bezier curve, I would like to calculate the subdivisions (in JavaScript) to approximate the curve with straight line segments within an angular tolerance (avoid too much of an angle between segments). I mainly want to see if there is already an efficient open source algorithm out there before I try to write my own.

Here is what I have found that is close do doing this:

https://github.com/turf-junkyard/turf-bezier - although it's not quite the same, I could use some of the code, since I already have the spline.

https://github.com/seanchas116/bezier-subdivide - this seems to do exactly what I want, although it looks like a recursive algorithm that would be costly to performance.

https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/ - getLUT() could be useful but I would need a way to decide how many steps.

http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/02/18/drawing-bezier-curves/ - pretty much what I want, but this isn't in Javascript.

http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/ - helpful theory.

Comment: I would use pomax's getLUT(). To calculate how many steps to use you can measure the distance from the curve midpoint to the midpoint between start and end point. If you want to take a look I have done something similar [here](https://github.com/fracalo/svg-contour/blob/master/src/utils/redraw-steep-curve.js#L7)

Comment: I would do the same. You're not really looking for subdivisions here so much as "flattening" (turning the curve into a polynomial), for which a LUT works best. Usually 32 steps is already enough to look just fine, but bumping up that value for twisty curves is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

This module should do what is needed: https://github.com/mattdesl/adaptive-bezier-curve